# Is it possible to trigger GPIO pins via web socket at specified date and time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webserver, raspberry-pi3

I am running nodejs webserver on my raspberry pi and I am building a web interface where a user can input a date and time where an gpio pin will be triggered based on the pre-set time. I have made a simple alarm clock using html and java but I don't know how to send the 1 and 0 to the raspberry pi when the alarm initializes.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Alarm Clock</title>
</head>


<body> 
 <input type="datetime-local" id="alarmTime" />
 <button onclick="setAlarm(this);" id="alarmButton">Set Alarm</button>
 
 <div id="alarmOptions" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="snooze();">Snooze 5 minutes</button>
  <button onclick="stopAlarm();">Stop Alarm</button>
 </div>
 
 <script>
  
  var alarmSound = new Audio();
  alarmSound.src = 'alarm.mp3';
  var alarmTimer;

 

  function setAlarm(button) {
   var ms = document.getElementById('alarmTime').valueAsNumber;
   if(isNaN(ms))  {
    alert('Invalid Date');
    return;
   }
   var alarm = new Date(ms);
   var alarmTime = new Date(alarm.getUTCFullYear(), alarm.getUTCMonth(), alarm.getUTCDate(),  alarm.getUTCHours(), alarm.getUTCMinutes(), alarm.getUTCSeconds());
   
   var differenceInMs = alarmTime.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();

   if(differenceInMs < 0) {
    alert('Specified time is already passed');
    return;
   }

   alarmTimer = setTimeout(initAlarm, differenceInMs);
   button.innerText = 'Cancel Alarm';
   button.setAttribute('onclick', 'cancelAlarm(this);');

  };
  
  function cancelAlarm(button) {
   clearTimeout(alarmTimer);
   button.innerText = 'Set Alarm';
   button.setAttribute('onclick', 'setAlarm(this);')
  };

  function initAlarm() {
   alarmSound.play();
   document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = '';
   console.log("ALAAAARM");
  };

  function stopAlarm() {
   alarmSound.pause();
   alarmSound.currentTime = 0;
   document.getElementById('alarmOptions').style.display = 'none';
   cancelAlarm(document.getElementById('alarmButton'));
  };

  
  
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using

```html
var socket = io(); 
window.addEventListener("load", function(){ 
  var Alarm = document.getElementById("alarmTime"); 
  Alarm.addEventListener("change", function() { 
    socket.emit("alarmTime", Number(this.checked));
```

and here is the js file:

```js
var http = require('http').createServer(handler); 
var fs = require('fs'); 
var io = require('socket.io')(http) 
var Gpio = require('onoff').Gpio; 
var LED = new Gpio(4, 'out'); 
   

http.listen(8080); 

function handler (req, res) { 
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/test.html', function(err, data) { 
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); 
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    } 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data); 
    return res.end();
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var lightvalue = 0; 
  
  socket.on('alarmTime', function(data) { 
    lightvalue = data;
    if (lightvalue != LED.readSync()) { 
      LED.writeSync(lightvalue); 
    }
  });
});

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  LED.writeSync(0); 
  LED.unexport(); 
  pushButton.unexport(); 
  process.exit(); 
});
```

Nothing is working. New to nodejs

Comment: What is the exact version of the pi do you have? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Connectors

Comment: raspberry pi 3 model B+. I just found a workaround. I just made a checkbox where the led in raspi responds to 1 and 0 base on the status of the checkbox and put the .trigger("click") jquery under the initAlarm function.so the checkbox will change status when the alarm triggers and when the checkbox changes status the led will also change from 0 to 1 and vice versa. I can't seem to get it working without using a reference object like the checkbox.